# Angular js routing didn't fire content javascript

Tags: angularjs

I'm using MVC and angular JS to render page. When I click a menu at menu panel, it will render the content on container on right side. 
However, I found the script inside the content page didn't fire after
render (only render the HTML part, javascript didn't run). What is the root cause on this and any solution?

```
<script>
var myapp = angular.module('myApp', ["ui.router"])
myapp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
      .state('Admin', {
          templateUrl: "/Admin/Member"
      });
})
</script>


  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse" style="margin:0;">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a ui-sref="Admin">Member</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
 <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You do not define `url`, please add url on which your template has to be load from `templateUrl : "Admin/Member"`.

Comment: What error your getting as in the Developer tools

Comment: @gaurav bhavsar : also not working.

Comment: @Aravind : No error.

Comment: can you expose your .cshtml page!

Comment: @ Aravind: added.

Comment: Where is javascript content ?

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS index page you have to add below line to find the root URL:

```
<script>
        var app_root = @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(new Uri(new Uri(this.Context.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)), Url.Content("~/")).ToString(), true));
    </script>
```

Then Add this path with your template URL like below:

```
myapp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('Admin', {
          templateUrl: app_root +"Admin/Member"
      });
})
```

Comment: also cannot work. I put a alert in content page but the alert didn't fire.

Comment: Check the browser console(F12) to make sure there is no (AngularJS)compile time error.